# Questions about $\subset$ and $\in$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to polish my set theory skills, can we say the following?

$\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\in \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\subset \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\{1,2\}\subset \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\{1,2\}\notin \{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$

$\{1\} \subset \{1,\{1\},\{\{1\}\}\}$ which element on the LHS make the RHS a subset?

Comment: The statements go false, true, false, false. Can you see why?

Comment: @J.G. 1. isn't it like $\{A,B\}\in \{A,B,C\}$? 4. $1$ and $2$ are not elements of $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ isn't it correct?

Comment: You have to recap the basic properties of the two relations : $\in$ and $\subset$. The $\in$ relation is the relation between a *set* (the rightand side) and its *element* (the lefthand side) : $a \in X$ means that $a$ is an *element* of set $X$.

Comment: The $\subset$ relation is the relation between two sets : $A \subset X$ means that set $A$ is a *subset* of set $X$.

Comment: A soldier is an *element* of a platoon, while a platoon is a subset of a brigade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ones true are the second and the fifth one. This is because there is a large distinction between 'contains' and 'is a subset'. Look at your definitions provided in the textbook to see why.

*EDIT*
Okay, so I figure that your understanding from set theory is not complete.

Let us define a couple things:

1.) A set is a well-defined object that is a collection of other objects. 
What this means is that a set contains things, it could be anything. 'Well defined' implies here, that is there is an exactly identical set out there containing the exact same things as a given set, then the two sets are equal.

2.) Every element in a set is called an element. Every element is distinct in a set; that means, ${x,x}={x}. An element may be a set; sets, as defined, are also objects.

3.) A subset of a set, is a set that contains elements of the set; it can have less elements than the set but it cannot have elements that are not contained in the set. Most importantly, it is a set.

Take, $\{1,2\}. 1$ is an element of this set (not a subset), but $\{1\}$ is a subset of the set, not an element. (Why? - $1$ is an object in the set and $\{1\}$ is not in the set but contains objects that are in the set.)

Comment: Thank you spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, I add another example to make sure I understand after reading the comments/amswers